# Can someone be on multiple superhero teams?

Tags: marvel, comics, super-hero

In the Marvel Universe, can someone be on multiple superhero teams? For example, be part of two different Avenger teams, or be part of The Future Foundation and still be on another team?

Comment: Do animated shows count? On TV, Hulk has been a member of the Avengers and S.M.A.S.H at the same time, and they have had episodes where he was going back and forth between them.

Comment: They can be on eight, because that's the maximum number of decoder rings they can wear. (The rings don't fit on thumbs.)

Comment: Is there anyway I can improve my answer?

Comment: Sounds like it's time to invent a new parody superhero, "The Joiner".

Answer (score 11):

Yes, as of [June, 2010](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/32702/new_avengers_2010_1), [Wolverine](http://marvel.com/universe/Wolverine_%28James_Howlett%29) was splitting his time across multiple teams, including the X-Men, two Avengers teams, and although unmentioned in the panel below, [The Uncanny X-Force](http://marvel.com/comics/series/9976/uncanny_x-force_2010_-_2012). All this, on top of his own solo books, and various guest spots.

[image: New Avengers #1]

Other notable characters who are members of multiple active groups include [Namor](http://marvel.com/characters/39/namor), [Hank McCoy](http://marvel.com/universe/Beast_%28Henry_McCoy%29), and [Benjamin Grimm](http://marvel.com/universe/Thing_%28Benjamin_Grimm%29).

Also worth mentioning, is the fact that Uncanny X-Force (or just X-Force in the actual books), is a secret sub-group of X-Men. If you wish to not count that as a "separate team" and view it more as a strike squad, there is also [The Avengers Unity Squad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncanny_Avengers), which is specifically made up of various X-Men and Avengers members originally including Captain America, Havok, Rogue, the Scarlet Witch, Thor and Wolverine.

[image: Wolvie and Ben]

[image: Avengers & Power Pack #3]

Even Wolverine has lost track of how many teams he is a member of.

Comment: One of my favorite Wolverine quotes and what sprung immediately to mind when I saw the question.

Comment: I recall another panel where he comes home from some random mission and, falls on the couch, and complains about being on too many teams, but I can't remember where it was.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, they can.

For example, [Spider-Man](http://marvel.com/characters/54/spider-man), who is currently on three superhero teams.

[image: Spider-Man character sheet.]

*Transcription of relevant text:*

> **Group Affiliations:**
>
> - Avengers,
> - formerly the Secret Defenders
> - "New Fantastic Four"
> - The Outlaws

Comment: Are the New Fantastic Four and the Outlaws current teams or also former teams? It's a little ambiguous just how many teams Spidey is currently a member of.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Wolverine has been on both The Avengers and X-Men for the last 10 years or so. I also think that Ben Grimm (The Thing) was on both New Avengers and The Fantastic Four at one point (maybe 5-6 years ago?) as well.